# Insert int from class to database (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, class, insert, int

I have two classes, from which I want one int number (first code) inserted into a database. The only thing I found so far is with a prepared statement, but I want the int from "freeparking" inserted into the database (second code) every hour. I have prepared a sleep thread already, which lets my second code initiate every full hour. But I am not sure how to insert the integer with my database. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
private void setFreieparkplätze(int freeparking) {
    this.freeparking = freeparking;
}

int freeparking = vehiclenumber.getParking();
```

}

```
static Connection connection = null;
static String databaseName = "";
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tiefgarage?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false" + databaseName;

static String username = "";
static String password = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    **PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT Into parkinglot(Numbers) VALUES (?)");** // ???

    int status = ps.executeUpdate();

    if (status != 0) {
        System.out.println("Database connected");
        System.out.println("Record was inserted");
    }
```

Comment: So you just ask how to insert an integer in a database? If so, the query will be:
"INSERT Into parkinglot(Numbers) VALUES ("+ getFreeparking() +")". 
Note that Numbers (table column) has to be integer type and getFreeparking() is just a getter for freeparking int variable.

Comment: Oh, yeah that was quiet easy. Thanks! Yeah its an integer type, I also got Date and Time columns in my database. Will these added automatically, when the Numbers will be inserted?

Comment: You should set the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### *I repeat my comment as answer to make it visible to anyone.*

The query to add an integer in a db shoould be like:

```
INSERT Into parkinglot(Numbers) VALUES ("+ getFreeparking() +");
```

Note that **Numbers** (table column) has to be integer type and **getFreeparking()** is just a getter for freeparking int variable.